# Play movie from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

my question is: I have a short introduction movie for my application and i want to show it when the application launches, the problem is that im not having any success.

Im using this code on the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method:

```
 MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"launch" ofType:@"mov"]]];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.view.frame = _window.bounds;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
[_window addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[_window makeKeyAndVisible];
//[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Best Regards

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do instead is out that code in your `RootViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` method. Or whatever other view controller is displayed. That kind of thing doesn't belong in the application delegate and you also shouldn't be adding subviews directly to your `UIWindow` instance.

Put the code in a view controller and add the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view as a subview to `self.view` and it should work fine.